# How to add Text under each of my images in a row

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I'm trying to have a product description for each shoe in a row. How would I go about doing that? Normally when I add a text it goes to the right of the shoe instead of under it. [image]

**Tournaments.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Card, Button, Spinner, CardSection, } from '../common';

class Tournaments extends React.Component {
 static navigationOptions= {
   tabBarLabel: 'Tournaments'
 }
   render() {
     return (

     <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
       <Card>
       <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
       <Image
         style={styles.logo}
         source={require('../../Images/ShoeJackCityLogo.png')}
       >
       </Image>
       </View>
       <View style={styles.formContainer} />
       </Card>
       <ScrollView>
       <ScrollView horizontal>
       <Card>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Image
          style={styles.product}
          source={require('../../Images/aj_4_toro.png')}
        />
        <Text style={styles.productDescription}>
         Air Jordan 4 Retro Toro Bravo
       </Text>

        <Image
          style={styles.product}
          source={require('../../Images/aj_4_toro.png')}
        />
      <Image
          style={styles.product}
          source={require('../../Images/aj_4_toro.png')}
      />
      </View>
      </Card>
     </ScrollView>

     <ScrollView horizontal>
      <Card>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <Image
        style={styles.product}
        source={require('../../Images/aj_4_toro.png')}
      />
      <Image
        style={styles.product}
        source={require('../../Images/aj_4_toro.png')}
      />
      <Image
        style={styles.product}
        source={require('../../Images/aj_4_toro.png')}
      />
    </View>
   </Card>
   </ScrollView>
   </ScrollView>
     </View>

   );
     }
   }
   const styles = {
 containerStyle: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: '#F13C20',
   paddingBottom: 20
 },
 logoContainer: {
     alignItems: 'center',
     flexGrow: 1,
     justifyContent: 'flex-start',
     paddingBottom: 15
 },
 logo: {
   paddingTop: 15,
   width: 50,
   height: 50,
 },
 product: {
   width: 100,
   height: 100,
   paddingBottom: 5,
   marginRight: 50
 },
 productDescription: {
   fontsize: 12,
   textAlign: 'center',
   fontStyle: 'italic',
   color: 'black'

 }
};
export default Tournaments;
```

Comment: Try to use `alignItems: 'center'`, or `justifyContent: 'center'` in
`<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>`

Comment: Are you trying to make a grid view layout?

Answer (score 1):

To make your text to be present below your image. give `flex` and `flexDirection:Column` to the `View` which wraps both image and Text.

```
<View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'column'}}>
 <Image .... />
  <Text>text here</Text>
 </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make parent view flexDirection: row and child views column (by default).

[here is the output that you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC5M2.png)

[Code of that output you can use your array and image instead of child view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5beXu.png)

Comment: I believe it's generally recommended to embed code in the answer rather than link to the external site. In this case the linked code is also a picture...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component for a single product with image and text and import them to render. You can use FlexBox to design any type of layout.
Go through the link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox

ProductCard.js

```
export default class ProductCard extends Component{
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
 }
 render(){
  return(
   <View style ={{flex:1, flexDirection:"column"}}>
     <View>
      <Image source = {this.props.imageURL} />  
     </View>
     <View>
      <Text>{this.props.imageText}</Text>
     </View>
   </View>
  )
 }
}
```

You can send image url and image text as a prop to the ProductCard component. And add as many times ProductCard. Later you can send response of products to the ProductCard component and use FlatList to render all the products.

ProductComponent.js

```
import ProductCard from "./ProductCard"
export default class ProductComponent extends Component{
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
 }
 render(){
  return(
   <View style ={{flex:1}}>
    <ProductCard imageURL = "URL OF IMAGE" imageText = "TEXT OF IMAGE" />
    <ProductCard imageURL = "URL OF IMAGE" imageText = "TEXT OF IMAGE" />
   </View>
  )
 }
}
```